# How to render an image from *.css.scss file in Rails 4 that is in a subfolder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

The image(s) is located in `assets/images/new_design/new_img1.png`.

In the `new_layout.css.scss` file, I have the following line:

```
.top_bg {
  background-image: url("/assets/new_design/new_img1.png");
  ...
}
```

But the image is not rendered. I've tried also:

1. `background-image: image-url("/assets/new_design/new_img1.png");`
2. `background-image: url("/assets/new_design/new_img1.png");`
3. `background-image: url("new_design/new_img1.png");`

But none of these worked. On localhost I am able to render it successfully with the third approach, but I don't know how to do it on the production server.

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Images placed inside of the /assets/ folder are brought into Rails using the asset pipeline. So, if you want to access them you'll need to append .erb to your file so you can put some ruby in to your css file that'll be evaluated by rails.

> Change new_layout.css.scss to new_layout.css.scss.erb

Now that you've got a file that can run helpers, use the image helper to generate the path for your image:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'new_design/new_img1.png' %>);
```

Should work. This utilizes an asset path helper, that looks through your asset folder for the appropriate resource and created a direct link.

If you're looking to directly access images without the pipeline, you can place them in the public folder of your application, but then you lose the value of using the asset pipeline.

As an addition, for production... You may need to precompile your assets before pushing to production if your process doesn't include this step in the launch.

Run the following to precompile your assets:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: So this is failing in prod or local or both? Can you inspect the element and see what path is actually being hooked up? Is it raising an exception in prod? More information than "doesn't work" could help figure out what the issues is.

Is the image located in app/assets/images/new_design/new_img1.png or did you wire up a root level assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before, and have been able to get away with having my image in my

`app/assets/images`

directory and be able to call the image using

`background-image: image-url("project-image.jpg");`

Btw. In production mode, assets are by default precompiled by the Asset Pipeline. All files included in `application.js` and `application.css` asset manifest are compressed and concatenated into their respective files of the same name, located in the `public/assets` folder.

Also, to include additional assets, you may specify them using the `config.assets.precompile` configuration setting.
```config.assets.precompile += %w( some-name.css )